# Request failed, repeatedly

Tags: bug, ios-app

I’m able to log in. As it’s requesting from the API, says request failed. Been like this for a coupla days. Whatever the app-equivalent of being bring is, I have it.

Just Feed apparently.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone10,1)
- OS Version: Version 12.1.2 (Build 16C101)

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes see this when my iPhone 5S is connected to my home WiFi.

If it persists a surefire way that I find fixes it is to disconnect from my WiFi and use 4G instead.

Perhaps you can test doing an equivalent in your setup.